# Android library with SyncAdapter not running in more than 1 app in the same phone

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

I am creating an **Android library** that uses SyncAdapter to do a small task in the background every day. This works perfectly fine if used in only one app. If the same library is used by two apps in the same phone, it gives `CONFLICTING_PROVIDER` error.

To fix this. I used `${applicationId}` in library manifest like:

```
<provider
    android:name=".sync.DummyProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.mysdk"
    android:exported="false"
    android:syncable="true" />
```

This generates dynamic authority for the provider.

Now, the problem is that SyncAdapter needs to have `contentAuthority` in the xml folder.

```
<sync-adapter
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="@string/sync_account_type"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
    android:contentAuthority="<-----NOT SURE WHAT TO ADD HERE----->"
    android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"
    android:supportsUploading="false"
    android:userVisible="false"/>
```

I tried `android:contentAuthority="${applicationId}.mysdk"` but applicationId doesn't get replaced by the app's package name. Instead, it take it as it is and gives error as:

```
E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for ${applicationId}.mysdk
```

These are the step I have tried till now

1. Creating stringValue from build.gradle in library's build.gradle file, but here applicationId can not be used there.
2. Moved contentAuthority in the Manifest, as ${applicationId} works there but nothing happens after doing this. contentAuthority needs to be in the xml folder.

Comment: I think you cannot access application id from xml. What you can do is ask your customers to add a string in strings.xml.

Comment: This worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@pranav-agraval](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3057564/pranav-agrawal)'s answer worked.

I didn't change anything in the SDK. The string resource I was using had a key `content_provider`.

I would have to ask any one who is using the SDK to add this key to their `string.xml` file. This should be of pattern `application_package_name.sdk_name`.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to declare the application id in your build.gradle file

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.package"
    ....
    }
```

Then use the following xml for your syncAdapter

```
<sync-adapter
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:contentAuthority="@string/account_authorities"
android:accountType="@string/account_type"
android:userVisible="false"
android:supportsUploading="false"
android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"/>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response.

But I can't really use applicationId in the android library.